# How to migrate a repo to git-lfs without losing all the commit history?

Tags: git, github, git-lfs

I have an existing git repository having large number of ".bmp" files scattered across multiple folders. I want to update this repository so that is uses Git-LFS. Is there a way to do this without losing all the commit history? While searching regarding this I came across a tool [BFG Repo-Cleaner](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/). But does this tool maintain the commit history of the said repository?

Comment: You should rethink the correct answer. The answer by @wtmatthias of using `git lfs migrate` looks like the best solution to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you mean by "maintain the commit history"...

You must know that git is based on hash (sha1) that "seal" the commit. If one of the data of a commit change, the sha1 of the commit change. And because commits are linked all the sha1 of the children commits changes also.

As a consequence, the history will change and you will annoy all the users of the repository if you force push the changes done by BFG.

That's why you should think twice if it worth to do it. But if you think it is, do it... with care ;-)

Answer (score 5):

(I use TortoiseGit, so there might be something it's doing behind the scenes that allows these steps to work for me. Please leave a comment if it seems this is the case.)

If you're OK with duplicating data between your old git repository (which means leaving the commit history untouched as desired), then do the following:

- Set up git lfs for your repo
- Add the gitattribute `*.bmp filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text` and commit this change
- In your file explorer, search for all .bmp files and delete all these files
- Revert all changes to your working copy
- Now all .bmp files should appear modified, even though they are the exact same files as in your old repository (the modification is actually an attribute change on the file telling it to add to git lfs, not a modification to the file itself)
- Commit these changes. This will push all your .bmp files to git lfs

You might think this is pointless because it just duplicates the exact same data between your old git repository and the new git lfs. If you don't want this duplication, you'll need to use something like BFG Repo-Cleaner as mentioned in the question.

...But we had some issues that meant it was necessary to do this process on our repo. Here's the background on why we did this (we were OK with duplication to fix the issue we had):

We had an existing repository with a large number of .png files scattered throughout, similar to your issue. We started using git lfs with this repository and added in a `*.png filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text` line to our .gitattributes. This meant that all existing .png files stayed in our old git repository and new files were added to our git lfs.

...But this caused an issue where .png files would sometimes show up as modified (even though the file contents were not modified) because their attributes were being changed. Committing these changes would add them to git lfs, but it became an nuisance because these changes could not be reverted and it would prevent easy switching between branches (unmodified files would need to be re-committed before being able to switch branches).

To resolve this problem, we needed to migrate *all* of our .png files to git lfs without modifying the commit history, just like this original question asked. Using the process I described was a simple, safe, and easy way to address this nuisance at the cost of duplicating data between the old repository git and new git lfs.

Comment: Great answer! After spending some time to migrate existing files into LFS with 'git lfs migrate' unsuccessfully, I used a similar approach like yours to migrate all binaries to LFS. What I did was remove binaries from cache using 'git rm --cached "*.png"' and just adding them with 'git add *.png"' provided that ,png is added into LFS Tracking List beforehand. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I used this [script](https://github.com/github/git-lfs/issues/326#issuecomment-104881826). In the Article its explained well and they also list some other ways to migrate the repo. For me it was fine to change the sha-1 values, as long as the history, author, date etc... are the same. So if you dont care about the sha-1 values that much, this script works pretty well.

Comment: @p-kar Let me know if it worked for you or if you run into trouble again.

Answer (score 0):

This may be obvious at this point, but there's seems to be a "best" option to migrating for the average use other than the great help in @Frossy's linked [script](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/326#issuecomment-104881826) mentioned above...see [git-lfs-migrate](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/wiki/Tutorial#migrating-existing-repository-data-to-lfs). Like I said this may be painfully obvious at this point, but as a git-lfs noob it wasn't to me a few days ago, and this question gets a lot of hits.

Additionally, I just saw at the bottom of @Frossy's script that there's some mention of git-lfs-migrate.